# Save microsoft account info

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-account

I would like to have an "autofill" so that every time windows asks for my microsoft account information it already has it.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of when Windows 8 asks for microsoft account info? I can do some peeking around with procmon.

Comment: @CalebJares MS office, mail, skydrive, anything with Xbox live integration

Comment: I can't get it to ask me to log in to my Microsoft Account. I've only had to do that once I think, when I set up my computer for the first time. Do you have a screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs if you've setup an account as a local account. I belive switching from local account to the Microsoft account results in the credentials being securely stored, allowing Metro apps to access them and hence you can install from store without having to re enter the password.

You should be able to switch from Settings → Users and clicking on "Switch to Microsoft Account" as exlained [here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/switch-between-local-and-microsoft-accounts/)

[image]

Comment: 1) is there a reason not to have an MS account? 2) Is there a way to get this without having the account an MS account?

Comment: 1 is up to you - there's no reason to *not* have a MS account - and Skydrive makes it worthwhile. 2. Nope, without a MS account there's no way to achieve. Note that a MS account doesn't necessarily mean a hotmail.com/outlook.com address - you can create a MS account using any email id.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager`

Comment: what do I do from there?

Comment: This is cool, nice find. I should explore the control panel some more.

Comment: @soandos It depends on what you wish to do? There are a lot of options for you to explore. You could create Web Credentials - Save login-passwords for websites (its saved thru IE as well). You could also create Microsoft Credentials for locations/websites which require your Microsoft Account info

Comment: @AbhishekGirish I want this for my modern apps

Comment: If you have logged in thru your Microsoft Account, it should never ask you for your credentials. I'm surprised why you'd even need it.